# How do I create a custom loop in wordpress that excludes categories listed in theme options

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom loop that excludes categories using this code:

`query_posts(array('category__not_in' => array(2,6)));`

Instead of specifying the categories to exclude in the code, I'd like to be able to set the option in my custom theme options menu.  The code to call the option is `get_option('ex_cats');`.  How do I call this in my query_posts statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this query_posts(array('category__not_in' => array(get_option('ex_cats'))));

or 
$cats_id = get_option('ex_cats');
query_posts(array('category__not_in' => array($cats_id)));

i assume get_option('ex_cats') will return a string value.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed, particularly defining $cats_id and inserting that.  I ended up putting it in an associative array so I could add some other parameters.  Thanks!